# ClearDB - does it take time to read the newest data?

Tags: mysql, database, azure, cleardb

I just used mySQL workbench to connect to my clearDB account which is connected to an azure web app. The problem is even thought I ran a query that drops/creates tables in the newly made schema that mirrors exactly the tables and data in my previous live server, I go to mysite.azurewebsites.com/wp-admin and the error is in establishing data connection. Site could not be found. Check if your database contains the following pages: wp_blogs, ..........

What could be the problem? Does this process just need a bit of time to propagate all the data?

EDIT: something to note, which might be a factor, when I ran the last query, it also included dropping/adding the table "wp_users" so all previous data was wiped and replaced with the info from a previous live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you will see any changes made immediately. But because your database is hosted on a geoseparated cluster in circular replication there are some rare circumstances where this might not be true.

Specifically, if your delete/write went to one master and your read query went to another. Data propagation is normally immediate but if one of the nodes is offline or the system is unusually busy there can be a delay.